# Consonants with accents

Tags: keyboard, android

What is the easiest way to type consonants with accents (acute, grave, circumflex) like k̂ ĵ d̂ r̂ ŵ or ĝ on android? Is there a keyboard app that let you customize the keys like this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way on Windows is to use the alt codes. Hold down Alt, then using the number pad, enter the number of the character you need.

https://www.alt-codes.net/

Android and iPhone seem like they need international keyboard apps.

Comment: There is no accented consonants in that list.

Comment: @Paracosmiste, look in the third column of each of the two tables, and you will see  Ç and ñ, for example.

Comment: Where's the rest? k̂ ĵ d̂ r̂ ŵ ĝ ...?